# Метод вывести массив в консоль с использованием дженериков

Tags: java

Необходимо реализовать метод с использованием обобщенных параметров типа, который в качестве аргумента будет принимать массив и выводить его в консоль. На входе массивы могут быть разных типов - `int, float, String`. Без использования встроенных методов Java таких, как `Arrays.toString` и т.д.
Как можно это сделать? Код, который написал я неверный. Почему?

```
public class PrintOutArray<T>{

    public static void printOutArray(<T>[] array){

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            System.out.print(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Нет, это Вы скажите почему он неверный :) Пробовали его запускать? Что получилось?

Comment: Это какая-то учебная или тестовая задача? Вы её дословно написали?

Comment: задача учебная. Idea выделяет красным array и пишет Cannot resove symbol 'array'.

Comment: Так скобки уберите T[] array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете даже параметризовать ваш метод, вместо всего класса, так будет правильнее:

```
public class PrintOutArray{

    public static <T> void printOutArray(T[] array){

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            System.out.print(array[i]);
        }
    }
}
```